# What is the difference between "three of you" and "three of us"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Does **"three of us"** include the person who says it?

OP's Additional Comment:

> The situation is ..... the fourth person is talking about other 3 people in the group of 4 saying "three of us ......". Is it the right usage? Or he should say "three of you"?

Comment: Yes, *us* includes the first person.

Comment: If YOU and your two friends are talking to the three students next door, *three of us* (that is *we*) are talking to *three of you* (students next door).

Comment: The situation is ..... the forth person is talking about other 3 people in the group of 4 saying "three of us ......". Is it the right usage? Or he should say "three of you"?

Comment: [*us*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/us): "1. *pronoun*
A speaker or writer uses us to refer both to **himself or herself** and to **one or more other people**."

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I catch what your confusion is.  Tell me if I understand correctly.  You are a member of a group of four people and you are talking to someone else about your group.  Three of the four people in your group want to go somewhere and the fourth does not, and you are explaining this to the outside person.

You would say, "Three of **us** want to go."  That is regardless of whether you are the one who disagrees.  "Us" refers to the group as a whole and you are a member of the group, so you are saying, "Three members of our group want to go."

If you wanted to clarify to the outside person that you are the one against the idea, you could say, "Everyone but me wants to go."

If you are the person in the group who doesn't want to go, and you are addressing just the other three members of the group, you could say, "The three of **you** go ahead."